# Windows mobile client for ASMX Web Service

Tags: windows, mobile, service

I try make simple Windows mobile client for web service. The web method only add two integer.  I add reference on proxy and System.Web.Service.
But it finish with this error :

```
The type 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

But I add reference on System.Web.Service
I check, and in reference is add :

Assembly System.Web.Services

**E:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Web.Services.dll**

I use Visual Studio 2008, where is a problem ? I try first google, but I didn't find answer. Thank

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've added a reference to the 3.5 version of system.web.services.dll, but it's asking for version 2.0. Try referencing the file at:

E:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\ **v2.0** \WindowsCE\System.Web.Services.dll

Comment: But if I try add dll System.Web.Service from .NET compact v2.0 I get error: The reference to System.Web.Service.dll could not be added. I understand ...